Windows share not working over WireGuard
I have a Mikrotik router, where I have set up WireGuard server. The connection is established from the Windows client PC using the official WireGuard client, and everything is working except the Windows shares.
The same mapping on the same laptop works when the machines are on the same network, but not via the VPN. It can't be a firewall problem on the server side, as disabling the firewall altogether makes no difference. In all other cases, if the firewall was set to interactive mode, it popped up the proper window (with the RDP connection for example). But not when trying to connect to the share. No name resolution can be the cause as I have used the IP address. Netbios over IP is enabled on the WireGuard interface as well. net view \\ipaddress\ returns error 53.
Alternatively, I tried SSH (OpenSSH server on the server side and winfsp/sshfs-win on the client side). It kinda works, but not really. You can do basic CRUD, but you can't keep files open as most Office apps would want. And because of the latency even creating a single file results in a set of new files (autonumbered).

Is this somehow a Win/Samaba issue? Or do I need something specific set up on the router?
Is there any other alternative to achieve mapping windows drives remotely via VPN?


You haven't actually told us the symptoms or details of the problem. You say it doesn't work, but how doesn't it work, exactly?

In any form or shape. Not even net view lists the shares. How can I be more specific? What do you want me to test?

@joeqwerty I don't know if this makes it more clear: when the server and the client are on the same network, all the mappings work as expected. When the client is trying to access the server via the established WireGuard VPN, nothing works, not even listing the shares. It seems, that no communication related to this is ever reaching the server. No trace in netstat, no event log entry, nothing. While RDP, HTTP, ssh, and many more services are accessible...

Does telnet to server port 445 work? (Or port 139, at least. That's how the SMB communication works over IP. Ancient versions of Windows used 139, nowadays it's 445.)
